# Why 'Error: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE' with rvest web scraping

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape web data but first step requires a login. I've successfully been able to log into other websites but I a weird error with this website.

```
library("rvest")
library("magrittr")    

research <- html_session("https://www.fitchratings.com/")

signin <- research %>%
  html_nodes("form") %>%
  extract2(1) %>%
  html_form() %>%
  set_values (
    'userName' = "abc",
    'password' = "1234"
     )

research <- research %>%
  submit_form(signin)
```

When I run the 'submit_form' line I get the following error:

```
> research <- research %>%
+ submit_form(signin)
Submitting with '<unnamed>'
Error: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

Submitting with unnamed is correct b/c there is no name assigned to the sign in button. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is this example still valid? When I run it, I get `Error: Unknown field names: userName, password`.

Comment: Also, it seems this problem was due to a bug in rvest and got solved by the rvest package author: https://github.com/hadley/rvest/issues/73 Unfortunately no official version of rvest (with the fix) has been released since. It may be possible to manually install the latest version from github though.

Answer (score 9):

I was having the same issue.  I jumped through a few hoops to get the dev version of rvest running, and it's working smoothly now.  Here's how I went about it:

First thing first.  You need to install RTools. Make sure R is closed out. This can be found here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/.
And information for the installation of Rtools can be found here (if you're using Windows): github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Install-Rtools-for-Windows

Boot up R, then install libraries "httr" and "Rcpp" if you don't have them already.

Install "devtools" and the correlated github installer.  Information can be found [here](https://github.com/hadley/devtools), but I'll give you a quick summary from the linked repo.

Windows:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
build_github_devtools()

#### Restart R before continuing ####
install.packages("devtools.zip", repos = NULL, type = "source")

# Remove the package after installation
unlink("devtools.zip")
```

Mac/Linux:

```
devtools::install_github("hadley/devtools")
```

Now, to run the final steps.

```
library(httr)
library(Rcpp)
library(devtools)
install_github("hadley/rvest")
```

You should now be able to run  `submit_form(session, form)` and not experience the error

```
Submitting with 'xxxx'
Error: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

Comment: Note: Rtools is only necessary on Windows. On Mac & Linux, installing a development package is trivial (it’s one command, as shown in your answer). In fact, I haven’t used CRAN in ages, I install everything from Github.